# two variables in one loop - first as a second variable

Tags: linux, bash, unix

```
for i in `seq 1 100` ;
do
    echo manager${i} ansible_host=$$i;
done
```

$1, $2, $3 etc have value

I want to first execute $i then execute $1 / $2 etc.
For example

```
$i = 5
$5 = 192.168.0.1
```

finally output which i want to get: `manager5 ansible_host=192.168.0.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this loop:

```
for i in {1..100}; do
    echo "manager$i ansible_host=${!i}"
done
```